# How can I store String objects in a Java ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am new in java. I just want that how can I store String objects(Variables) in an arraylist in java.

Here is my sample code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test_Class {
    String first="hello";
    String second="bye";

    List<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    myArray.add(first);
    myArrray.add(second);
}
```

But this code is not working for me. Please suggest me where I am doing wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: Not working. What is the error?

Comment: What means `But this code is not working for me`?

Comment: And why is this question upvoted ..

Comment: @underdog I have been noticing this pattern for a while now. Could be the case of multiple accounts.

Comment: Probably the fact that `myArrray` is spelled wrong...

Comment: @Steve arrrrrrrrrrrrr...ay

Answer (score 1):

You should have a [`main`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/?hc_location=ufi) method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String first="hello";
    String second="bye";

    List<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    myArray.add(first);
    myArrray.add(second);
}
```

You cannot have this code outside a method/constructor. See the [JLS - Chapter12. Execution](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

this code

```
List<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();
myArray.add(first);
myArray.add(second);
```

must be inside a methode or the constructor:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test_Class {
    String first="hello";
    String second="bye";
    List<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Test_Class (){
       myArray.add(first);
       myArray.add(second);
    }
}
```

or

```
public class Test_Class {
    String first="hello";
    String second="bye";
    List<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void myMethod(){
       myArray.add(first);
       myArray.add(second);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple example to Store user-defined objects in arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] a) {
    ArrayList<Employee> emps = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    emps.add(new Employee("XXXX", "YYYY"));
    emps.add(new Employee("ZZZZ", "AAAAA"));
    System.out.println(emps);
    Employee e = emps.get(1);
    e.setLastName("DDDD");
    System.out.println(emps);
  }
}

class Employee {
  private String lastName;
  private String firstName;
  public Employee(String lastName, String firstName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }

  public String getLastName() {
    return this.lastName;
  }

  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
  }

  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }
}
```